# How to enable Security(CSRF) alone in Cake 2.0

Tags: cakephp, csrf

I am trying to enable CSRF security in Cakephp 2.0

I have included the Security component in my controller.

```
public $components = array( 'Security');
```

I want to enable this component for only one function, say function test.

Other functions must be free of Security

I have tried to do like

```
$this->Security->requireSecure('test');
```

I have provided it like this as i want to enable security in test function alone.

In cakephp3.0 I found a option for enabling CSRF alone. But i need the solution for cakephp 2.0

I don't need any other securities validatePost, requirePost, requireDelete etc..

Awaiting for the feedbacks. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF should be enabled in every action/form by default, and disabled for any action you want, not the backwards.

```
public $components = array('Security');

private $disabledCSRFForActions = array("test");

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if (isset($this->Security) && in_array($this->action, $disabledCSRFForActions) {
            $this->Security->validatePost = false;
            $this->Security->enabled = false;
            $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
    }
}
```